# Как задать условие Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно чтобы при создании новой строки в таблице users,проверялось условие:
Если у нового пользователя в столбце 'ref_use' есть какая-то цифра(id участника,который пригласил этого нового пользователя),то проверялся весь список пользователей и тому пользователю,id которого равен этому 'ref_use' в столбец 'referals' прибавлялась единица(т.е. счетчик).И у скольких человек в таблице в столбце 'ref_use',стоит id этого человека,такое число было написано в столбце referals

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `ref_percent` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
  `referals` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zarabotok` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `login2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_admin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_yt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_use` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opened` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_link` varchar(256) DEFAULT 'none',
  `deposit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bonus_money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016-11-08 21:32:40',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: используйте триггер. если хотите помощь с решение - дайте данные и пример того, как должно отработать решение

Comment: Если бы я знал где это взять,то не создавал бы вопрос)Какие данные вам нужны ?

Comment: заполните несколько строк в таблице (не обязательно все столбцы, только основные) и покажите, что должно произойти с ними, когда будет вставляться новая строка

Comment: INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `avatar`, `money`, `ref_percent`, `ref_percent2`, `referals`, `zarabotok`, `wallet`, `telega`, `skype`, `login`, `login2`, `is_admin`, `is_yt`, `ref_use`, `profit`, `opened`, `ref_link`, `deposit`, `bonus_money`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Алексей Котов', 'https://pp.userapi.com/c846120/v846120570/88e8f/zwxekPNeVOk.jpg?ava=1', 0, 26, 50, 0, NULL, '', '', '', 'id427761187', '427761187', 0, 1, NULL, 20, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 'wL3VIohg8V6BbIq0wx0i65Yu0PWSCqoEXReAmdlSdZkuuydd0j7Km5iA1HLV', '2018-07-18 19:03:26', '2018-07-18 23:03:26')

Comment: 7 по счету идет referals,нужно чтобы в нем отображалось кол-во рефералов,т.е столько человек,у скольких в столбце 'ref_use' id этого человека

Comment: 16 по счету идет столбец 'ref_use'

Answer (score 0):

Используйте триггер. Как вариант, можете использовать этот (работоспособность не проверял, под рукой нет БД):

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   if ref_use is not null
   then UPDATE users SET referals = referals + 1 WHERE id = new.ref_use;
  end if; 
  END;
```